# These 2 SQL queries return different result

Tags: mysql, sql

Why these two queries are giving different results for `role`?

**RIGHT** result (role is rightly associated to user):

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    activations.id AS activation
    (SELECT
        roles.name
    FROM roles
    INNER JOIN role_users ON roles.id = role_users.role_id
    WHERE role_users.user_id = users.id
    LIMIT 1) AS role
FROM users
LEFT JOIN activations ON users.id = activations.user_id
```

---

**WRONG** result (role is always the first record of `roles` table):

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    activations.id AS activation
    (SELECT
        roles.name
    FROM roles
    INNER JOIN role_users ON roles.id = role_users.role_id
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = role_users.user_id
    LIMIT 1) AS role
FROM users
LEFT JOIN activations ON users.id = activations.user_id
```

I can't use the first query (with `WHERE role_users.user_id = users.id`) and I have to use the second one (with 'JOIN'): how to achieve the right result?

Thanks

EDIT: to answer the comments:

1. `I can't use the first query` means, in short, that I'm building it with Laravel Query Builder, and the expression `WHERE role_users.user_id = users.id`, translated into `->where('role_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')` in Laravel Query Builder, doesn't work because it's handled as if it was `WHERE role_users.user_id = 'users.id'`.
   I can use whereRaw() but I'd like to avoid this, and looking for a better solution
2. I didn't build the database schema but it comes from Cartalyst Sentinel; it's a many-to-many relation but I take care that every user has only one role, and if a user has more that one role, well, take the first (as there was an `ORDER BY roles.id`)

Comment: What mean `I can't use the first query` ,,, if that give you the Right result what is the problem?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept. In this instance, I cannot see what the LIMIT is supposed to be doing. In short, if either query returns a correct result, it's by luck rather than intention.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery isn't joining on your main query so it isn't tying the users together. Try this:

```
   SELECT
        u.*,
        activations.id AS activation
        (SELECT
            roles.name
        FROM roles
        INNER JOIN role_users ON roles.id = role_users.role_id
        INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = role_users.user_id AND u1.id = u.id
        LIMIT 1) AS role
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN activations ON u.id = activations.user_id
```

Comment: Uhm... this makes sense but I get a "[Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'users'"

Comment: Edited the SQL. Try again and let me know if that works.

Comment: this time I get this: `[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT roles.name FROM roles INNER JOIN role_use' at line 4`

Answer (score 0):

First query you are using the user from external query

```
SELECT
    /
    (SELECT
        roles.name
    FROM roles
    INNER JOIN role_users ON roles.id = role_users.role_id
    WHERE role_users.user_id = users.id 
                                ^^^^    -- external query user_id
    LIMIT 1) AS role
FROM users   --- you use this user, so each row has a different user_id
LEFT JOIN activations ON users.id = activations.user_id
```

Second query you select the first role from the user table, and is the same for every row.

Comment: Is there a solution for this?